# Cross-platform library using platform-specific dependency

Tags: c++, cmake

I am curious about how it would be possible to create a cross-platform library (built with CMake) that has seemingly platform-specific dependencies.

For example, say I create a library using GLEW or OpenGL, and during development I download their windows adaptation (`glew_x64-windows` or `opengl_x64-windows` for example), how could I go about ensuring that my library will still have the cross-platform portability I desire?

It is possible that I misunderstand the point of "suffixing" `windows`, or I just have a poor understanding of cross-platform libraries as a whole, but if that is not the case, my question stands.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The secondary question was intended to display my train of thought in an attempt to foster discussion, nevertheless I shall edit it out to adhere to your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option: Generally you would just ask cmake to find the library for you, via [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html). This will get the platform-specific version of that library that's already installed on the system that's doing the compilation. You won't have to worry about what platform you're on in this case.

Less-good option: If you've downloaded prebuilts of the platform-specific libraries for all of your target systems, you can create an [imported library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries) for each platform. Something like this should work, but I haven't tested it:

```
if(WIN32)
  add_library(glew STATIC IMPORTED)
  set_property(TARGET glew PROPERTY
             IMPORTED_LOCATION "path/to/libglew-windows.a")
  target_include_directories(glew SYSTEM AFTER PUBLIC "path/to/windows/include")
else()
  add_library(glew STATIC IMPORTED)
  set_property(TARGET glew PROPERTY
             IMPORTED_LOCATION "path/to/libglew-linux.a")
  target_include_directories(glew SYSTEM AFTER PUBLIC "path/to/linux/include")
endif()

# Then you can use it as a platform-independant target:
target_link_libraries(my_app PRIVATE glew)
```